# Nested function containing list comprehension

Tags: list, f#, syntax-error

I can have a function like this:

```
let readLines (filePath:string) = [
    use sr = new StreamReader (filePath)
    while not sr.EndOfStream do
        yield sr.ReadLine ()
]
```

But I cannot have a function like this:

```
let lines (f:string) =
    let readLines (filePath:string) = [
        use sr = new StreamReader (filePath)
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            yield sr.ReadLine ()
    ] in readLines f
```

I get the error:

```
Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.
```

I cannot wrap my head around this error. I would expect a list of string from 'lines'.

Comment: Try indenting the closing brace (or drop the `in` and put `readLines f` on the next line).

Comment: You are scarily correct, sir, and thanks a lot for that. The question now is, why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal change to make your second snippet compile is to insert two (or one) more space before the closing square bracket:

```
let lines (f:string) =
    let readLines (filePath:string) = [
        use sr = new StreamReader (filePath)
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            yield sr.ReadLine ()
      ] in readLines f
```

The reason is that the body of a `let` binding needs to be indented further than the `let` keyword - the F# compiler uses this to determine where the body expression of the function ends. This is also what the error message is trying to say "this 'let' is unfinished" almost always means that you do not have a valid expression inside `let`.

As @kvb mentioned in a comment, a more idiomatic way of writing this is to fully rely on the fact that the F# compiler is whitespace-sensitive and will infer where the `in` keywords are in correctly indented code. My personal preference is to also put `[` on a new line:

```
let lines (f:string) =
    let readLines (filePath:string) = 
      [ use sr = new StreamReader (filePath)
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            yield sr.ReadLine () ]
    readLines f
```